# sencha touch + phonegap: event not fired

Tags: android, eclipse, sencha-touch, applaud

When the first view (a form.Panel) of my app (developed in Sencha Touch) is painted, I need to check the contents of a local database. To do so, I trap the painted event of that first view. That works fine in Chrome. However, when I debug the app on my device (Asus Transformer tf101) using eclipse with the Applaud phonegap bundle, the painted event is never fired (I log a message to the console, which I can see in Chrome's console, using Sencha Touch only, but which never appears in eclipse's logCat, using eclipse with Applaud.)
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some code? What version of Phonegap are you using?

Comment: Apologies to gardenofwine and to anyone else reading this thread. Thanks also to gardenofwine for following it up. I had made a mistake in copying files from my sencha location to the eclipse workspace.